# Release deployment products (Web + App + SQL)

Tags: .net, deployment, release, release-management

I would like to have a push-button deployment solution so that I can just give a program to the customer's operations and they can deploy everything.

I need something that handles:

- SQL updates
- IIS web deployment (with environment-specific config files)
- .NET Windows service deployment (with environment specific config files)
- .NET Windows application (with environment specific config as well).

I didn't see anything on MSDN relating to that.

I already have MSIs for the application and the services (but different ones based on the environment).
I also have the zip packages for the web publication already (again one package per environment).

A quick browsing show [that](http://www.repliweb.com/products/r1-d/index.php) product. It looks like it could be helpful.
Then there's [this one](http://sdcm.kwatee.net/) but it is brand new and is a web app.
And [that one](http://www.noliosoft.com/product/nolio-automation-center) but it looks like it does only web apps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The InRelease product can do exactly what you need (disclosure: I am part of the dev team): http://inreleasesoftware.com/